# Can I add metadata to git commits? Or can I hide some tags in gitk

Tags: git, tags, metadata, gitk

I want to associate custom metadata with a `git commit`.  Specifically to record a review ID from a code review but it could be anything.  Tags seem a natural way to do that but I expect to have a review for every commit and I don't want to clutter `gitk` with tons of tags.  Is there some other mechanism to add custom metadata?  Can I make certain tags invisible?  If I could tell `gitk` not to display tags matching some pattern or RE, that would likely work but I don't see a way to do that.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

That's precisely what [git notes](http://Kernel.Org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html) are for.

Comment: Awesome!  Except I don't see that in git version 1.6.0.6.  When was it added?

Comment: @Chris Nelson: The patch was first sent to the mailinglist in July 2007 (sometime during the 1.5.3 timeframe). It was commited December 2008 (1.6.2). However, it didn't make it into a release until January 2010 (1.6.6). BTW: 1.6.0.6 is almost 1.5 years old and if I remember correctly, there have been a couple of security holes fixed since then.

Comment: As Jörg says, it's a recent addition - and development is still relatively active. Seems likely more notes-related features will be added as time goes on.

Comment: @Jefromi: Yep. Just tacking some freeform text annotations onto commits should be relatively safe, though. I don't expect major changes to *existing* notes features, only the addition of new ones. The Git community is very much commited to backwards compatibility. Also, the current codebase *has* been cooking for three years now, so the features that are currently in there, have had extensive review and testing.

Comment: @Jörg: Right, I did say features added, not features changed. Git is indeed very very good about backwards compatibility (and testing). I didn't mean to imply any sort of instability - just that it's a cool feature getting cooler (especially in case the OP found some individual subfeatures lacking). For example, automatic copying of notes on rebases wasn't added until 1.7.1, I think.

Comment: From what we've been able to figure out, git-notes was added at 1.6.6 and our newer systems here have 1.7.0 on them.  My remaining question would be how an older core would handle notes.  If I have 1.6.0 on my server and 1.7.0 on my workstation and I push a commit, what's going to happen?  (That's rhetorical; I'm going to try it and we'll likely upgrade across the board anyway.)

Comment: I don't seem to be able copy notes from repo to repo.  I have 1.7.0 on my sysetm, I created a new local repository, created a file, commited some changes, added some notes, and created a local clone (git-clone file:///...).  The cloned repo doesn't have any notes.  There's no mention of "notes" on the git-clone man page or "clone" on the git-notes man page.  I'm stumped.

Answer (score 76):

### Git-notes

With `git notes` you can add a “note” to a commit. You can also add them
to other Git objects, but let’s just focus on commits since that is what
the question is about.

A note is a Git object, and can in principle be “whatever” (arbitrary
data). But we’ll focus on something simple and textual for our purposes.

#### Example: review id

The question mentions review ids, so let’s make up some way to represent
such a thing. I don’t know what review ids really look like, but
hopefully the following would be sensible:

```
Review-id: 42
```

So this is effectively a key-value pair. Let’s add the above string to
the current commit:

```
git notes add -m "Review-id: 42"
```

If you run `git log` the note will be shown inline: [1]

```
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Date:   Tue Nov 8 21:10:25 2016 +0100

    Implement feature x

Notes:
    Review-id: 42
```

#### Another example

Of course you can add more “subnotes” to this note (we will stick with
the simple `key: value` syntax, one value per line). For example, if you
found out three months later that the commit message got something
wrong, just append the correction to the note:

```
git notes append --no-separator -m "Errata: It was actually feature y."
```

`git log`:

```
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Date:   Tue Nov 8 21:10:25 2016 +0100

    Implement feature x

Notes:
    Review-id: 42
    Errata: It was actually feature y.
```

We use `git notes append` in order to easily add this extra data to the
note. You could also use `git notes edit` in order to edit the file
directly.

Of course, since a Git note is just a single mutable file, you can run
into merge conflicts. To make that less likely, you can:

1. Stick to simple data like the above (one key-value per line).
2. Use special merge strategies; see `man git-notes`, section “Notes
   merge strategies”.

#### Visibility

The OP asked:

> Can I make certain tags invisible?

By default, `git log` only shows one note, namely
`.git/refs/notes/commits`. `commits` is just one note in the namespace.
Maybe you want *issues* to be in their own namespace:

```
git notes --ref=issues add -m "Fixes: #32"
```

Since this is stored in `.git/refs/notes/issues` and not in
`.git/refs/notes/commits`, “Fixes: #32” won’t show up when you run
`git log`. So you have effectively made such notes invisible by default.

If you want it to be shown, pass `--notes=issues` to `git log`:

```
$ git log --notes=issues
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Date:   Tue Nov 8 21:10:25 2016 +0100

    Implement feature x

Notes (issues):
    Fixes: #32
```

But now `.git/refs/notes/commits` are hidden. That one can easily be
included as well:

```
$ git log --notes=issues --notes=commits
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Date:   Tue Nov 8 21:10:25 2016 +0100

    Implement feature x

Notes (issues):
    Fixes: #32

Notes:
    Review-id: 42
    Errata: It was actually feature y.
```

There are variables to configure which notes are shown by default; see
`man git-config`.

#### Benefits compared to commit messages

Metadata can of course be recorded in the commit message directly. [1] But
commit messages are immutable, so to change them really means to make a
whole new commit, with all the rippling consequences that that entails.
Git-notes on the other hand are mutable, so you are always able to
revise them. And each modification of a note is of course version
controlled. In our case, for `.git/refs/notes/commits`:

```
$ git log refs/notes/commits
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
commit 9f0697c6bbbc6a97ecce9834d4c9afa0d668bcad
Date:   Tue Nov 8 21:13:52 2016 +0100

    Notes added by 'git notes append'

commit b60997e49444732ed2defc8a6ca88e9e21001a1d
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Date:   Tue Nov 8 21:10:38 2016 +0100

    Notes added by 'git notes add'
```

Another benefit is that you can put metadata that might only be useful or interesting in certain circumstances. For example, the Git project stores the email message id of where the patch of the commit came from:

```
commit 5b2424b658701c16e4fe12babf83fdb15d0f165a
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Thu Oct 12 10:28:16 2023 -0700

    grep: -f <path> is relative to $cwd

    Just like OPT_FILENAME() does, "git grep -f <path>" should treat
    the <path> relative to the original $cwd by paying attention to the
    prefix the command is given.

    Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>

Notes (amlog):
    Message-Id: <xmqqedhzg37z.fsf@gitster.g>
```

Here we can paste the message id at the end of:

```
https://lore.kernel.org/git/
```

And get a link to the patch email and in turn all the discussion on it:

https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqbkd4lwj0.fsf_-_@gitster.g/

#### Drawbacks compared to commit messages

The biggest drawback is if you use rewrite mechanisms beyond git-rebase(1) and `git commit --amend` (like git-cherry-pick(1), if you consider that “rewriting”); see the later “rewrites” section.

Also, it’s one (or more, if more namespaces are used) more level of indirection. If you are sure about your metadata prior to committing it to the “permanent history” then you can just add it to the commit message.

Nothing to miss or forget to fetch. No context that can be elided.

#### Sharing notes

Your notes aren’t shared by default; you have to do so explicitly. And
compared to other refs, sharing notes isn’t very user-friendly. We have
to use the *refspec* syntax:

```
git push origin refs/notes/*
```

The above will push all of your notes to your remote.

It seems that fetching notes is a bit more involved; you can do it if
you specify both sides of the refspec:

```
git fetch origin refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
```

So that’s definitely not convenient. If you intend to use Git-notes
regularly, you’ll probably want to set up your gitconfig to always fetch
notes:

```
[remote "origin"]
    …
    fetch = refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
```

This will fetch all notes from the remote but refuse to update your
local ref if the update is not a fast-forward. If you want to always
update your local ref according to the remote (even if it is not a
fast-forward), add an `+`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    …
    fetch = +refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*
```

Say you want to follow the aforementioned `amlog` notes on the
[GitHub Git mirror](https://github.com/git/git). Then you can add this:

```
[remote "o"]
    url = https://github.com/git/git/
    […]
    fetch = +refs/notes/amlog:refs/notes/amlog
```

Note that we need `+` here since the history is regularly
squashed.

#### Side note: enable reflog for all ref updates

Once you start getting into the business of sharing notes, you should
enable the reflog for *all* refs so that you have reflogs for all of
your notes.

```
[core]
    […]
    logAllRefUpdates = always
```

That way you can reset a fetch that force-updated your notes:

```
c4c120de490 refs/notes/commits@{1}: fetch gitster: forced-update
c5acdf419f0 refs/notes/commits@{2}: notes: Notes added by 'git commit --amend'
```

(Here we want the penultimate commit)

By using:

```
git update-ref -m 'Bad fetch' refs/notes/commits c5acdf419f0
```

#### Carry over notes on rewrites (different mechanisms)

The story here is checkered. Some rewrite mechanisms work with notes (with some setup) while others do not.

##### Rebase and amend

Git has the inconvenient default that notes are not carried over when a commit
is rewritten with git-rebase(1) and `git commit --amend`.  So if you for
example rebase a series of commits, the notes will not carry over to the
new commits.

The variable `notes.rewrite.<command>` is by default set to `true`, so one might
assume that notes *are* carried over.  But the problem is that the variable
`notes.rewriteRef`, which determines *which* notes will be carried over, has no
deafult vaule.  To set this value to match all notes, execute the following:

```
git config --global notes.rewriteRef "refs/notes/*"
```

Now all notes will be carried over when doing rewrite operations like `git rebase` and `git commit --amend**.

##### git-cherry-pick(1)

Notes rewriting does not work with git-cherry-pick(1). [3]

##### git-filter-repo(1)

This is a third-party tool but is the commonly recommended program to be used instead of the inferior built-in git-filter-branch(1).

Rewriting notes does *not* work when using this tool. See [this issue](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/issues/22).

#### Sharing notes in email patches (note: not for storing)

If you are using `git format-patch` to format your changes to be sent as emails,
and you have some metadata stored as Git notes, you can pass the `--notes`
option to `git format-patch` in order to append the notes to the email draft.

But keep in mind that this switch doesn’t really seem like it is meant
for sharing notes as metadata; they are just added between the commit
message and the patch proper part, in the free-form information
section. So (like larsks [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683248/can-i-add-metadata-to-git-commits-or-can-i-hide-some-tags-in-gitk/40496777#comment69143470_40496777) in the comments) you might
just want to incorporate the data in the commit message, if you really
want to share the note as proper metadata.

---

#### Changelog (major)

- 2023-04-28: caveat about `git-format-patch` (thanks to larsks)
- 2024-01-29:

  - Flesh out “rewrite” section
  - Add a “drawbacks” section (thanks to larsks)
  - Mention another benefit
- 2024-02-18:

  - Don’t emphasize force-update `+` refspec
  - Add side-note section about `logAllRefUpdates`

#### Notes

1. “This is the default for `git log` […] when there is no `--pretty`,
   `--format`, or `--oneline` option given on the command line.” ― `man git-log`, git version 2.10.2
2. One practice/convention for metadata-in-commit-messages that is used in projects like e.g. Git and the Linux kernel is to add key–value pairs in the “trailer” of the commit message, i.e. at the bottom.   See for example [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=19be0eaffa3ac7d8eb6784ad9bdbc7d67ed8e619) by Linus Torvalds:

   ```
   mm: remove gup_flags FOLL_WRITE games from __get_user_pages()
   This is an ancient bug that was actually attempted to be fixed once
   (badly) by me eleven years ago in commit 4ceb5db9757a ("Fix
   get_user_pages() race for write access") but that was then undone due to
   problems on s390 by commit f33ea7f404e5 ("fix get_user_pages bug").

   In the meantime, the s390 situation has long been fixed, and we can now
   fix it by checking the pte_dirty() bit properly (and do it better).  The
   s390 dirty bit was implemented in abf09bed3cce ("s390/mm: implement
   software dirty bits") which made it into v3.9.  Earlier kernels will
   have to look at the page state itself.

   Also, the VM has become more scalable, and what used a purely
   theoretical race back then has become easier to trigger.

   To fix it, we introduce a new internal FOLL_COW flag to mark the "yes,
   we already did a COW" rather than play racy games with FOLL_WRITE that
   is very fundamental, and then use the pte dirty flag to validate that
   the FOLL_COW flag is still valid.

   Reported-and-tested-by: Phil "not Paul" Oester <kernel@linuxace.com>
   Acked-by: Hugh Dickins <hughd@google.com>
   Reviewed-by: Michal Hocko <mhocko@suse.com>
   Cc: Andy Lutomirski <luto@kernel.org>
   Cc: Kees Cook <keescook@chromium.org>
   Cc: Oleg Nesterov <oleg@redhat.com>
   Cc: Willy Tarreau <w@1wt.eu>
   Cc: Nick Piggin <npiggin@gmail.com>
   Cc: Greg Thelen <gthelen@google.com>
   Cc: stable@vger.kernel.org
   Signed-off-by: Linus Torvalds <torvalds@linux-foundation.org>
   ```

   See:

   - `man git-interpret-trailers`
   - [submitting-patches](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/process/submitting-patches.rst) documents the common trailers used in the Linux Kernel project
   - [This Kernel Wiki page](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/CommitMessageConventions) which lists various trailer lines
     (usually key–value pairs) that are used in various projects.
3. I’m pretty sure that this has been discussed on the Git mailing list. The best source I could find is [this](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqqlga11jwp.fsf@gitster-ct.c.googlers.com/).

Comment: You need to add the "drawbacks compared to commit messages" section: if you rebase a branch, all your commits get new commit ids and all your notes are now gone with the wind (well, not "gone", but they remain associated with the original commit ids and are not attached to the commits that now make up your branch).  Notes will also not be preserved as part of a "git format-patch" operation, so if something is of general interest (like an issue id), you are better of leaving it in your commit message.

Comment: @larsks “if you rebase a branch, all your commits get new commit ids and all your notes are now gone with the wind ...” — see my latest edit.

Comment: @larsks “ Notes will also not be preserved as part of a "git format-patch" operation ...” — see my latest edit.

Comment: @larsks You were right about sharing notes via format-patch. I’ve updated that section now.

Comment: How can I sign notes?

Comment: @HendrikMHalkow There is no direct support for GPG signing notes. But Git Notes are just commits so I suppose you could fix them up with `git commit` manually. But then you would also have to use `git update-ref` in order to update the notes ref to the amended (signed) commit.

Comment: @larsks I’ve added a “drawbacks” section. The commit message itself is a good place for metadata in many cases.