# Is git notes the intended way to add category-style information to a commit?

Tags: git

The answer to [Can I add metadata to git commits? Or can I hide some tags in gitk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683248/can-i-add-metadata-to-git-commits-or-can-i-hide-some-tags-in-gitk) mentions git notes as a way to add metadata to a git commit.

Is git notes, possibly taking advantage of its namespace functionality in case I want to add other types of notes, the best way to categorize commits? For example, I'd like to categorize commits into "refactoring", "change-functionality", "bug-fix", "bug-introduce", and be able to ask git to only list commits that are in certain categories.

Answer (score 2):

What you are proposing is quite similar to what the [ruby-based gem "step-up"](https://github.com/kawamanza/step-up) is doing, based on `git notes`.

> The great goal of [this Gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/step-up) is giving to developers an easy way to manage these notes.
>
> With a culture of notating all the relevant developments, its possible to retrieve a summary of a range of versions besides that specifying what kind of information will be retrieved.
>   For example, imagine that you want to see all the features implemented in your application since the version v1.10.1 up to v2.0.0

```
stepup notes --since v1.10.1 upto v2.0.0 --sections pre_deploy pos_deploy
```

> The result would be something like the following:

```
Showing notes since v1.10.1 up to v2.0.0 (including notes of tags: v1.10.1, v1.10.2, v1.51.0, v2.0.0)
---
Pre-Deploy:

  - dependency of version v10 of project XYZ
  - it needed to rename the following file
    - config/environment_variables.yml.sample -> config/environment_variables.yml
  - rake articles:index

Pos-Deploy:

  - Reindex articles
    - rake articles:index
  - rake db:seed
  - rake categories:reload
```

[`ranged_notes.rb`](https://github.com/kawamanza/step-up/blob/master/lib/step-up/ranged_notes.rb) will define functions to get all the relevant commits, based on their notes.
[`git.rb`](https://github.com/kawamanza/step-up/blob/master/lib/step-up/driver/git.rb) contains the actual `git notes` commands.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what the intentions of the original authors of git-notes(1) were. But I would personally say no.

git-notes(1) is for adding mutable metadata to commits. So sure, if the categories are mutable (e.g. you might want to add categories a while after a commit has been made and you don’t want to change that commit) then git-notes(1) might be useful. But why use multiple namespaces?  Why not store them under one namespace? A category (I imagine) is just a keyword, and you can easily append simple strings to a note. So you might end up with something like this for a note:

```
bug fix

breaking change

refactor
```

After doing:

```
git notes --ref=yourref --append -m 'bug fix'
git notes --ref=yourref --append -m 'breaking change'
git notes --ref=yourref --append -m 'refactor'
```

But if you just need immutable metadata (i.e. you know what categories you want when writing the commit) then it’s simpler to just add the categories to your commit message:

```
Big change #4564

Keywords: breaking change, refactor, bugfix
```

I’ve used the name “Keywords” here.

This might be a log:

```
$ git log --patch
commit 498cc43746aa89a0bb335781eb8157908da12532 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Date:   Fri Sep 24 21:01:47 2021 +0200

    Set the scene

    Keywords: worldbuilding

diff --git a/novel.md b/novel.md
index 8bf53766294f..999578522b1f 100644
--- a/novel.md
+++ b/novel.md
@@ -1 +1,4 @@
 Once upon a time there was an ogre.
+
+He lived in an ogre village in South-Okranazoa, the highlands west of
+the lowlands and plains of Kzherbadai.

commit b307a1c02eec479888cba7676e00903071fb0878
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Date:   Fri Sep 24 20:59:46 2021 +0200

    Start the story

    Keywords: intro, ogrekin

diff --git a/novel.md b/novel.md
new file mode 100644
index 000000000000..8bf53766294f
--- /dev/null
+++ b/novel.md
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Once upon a time there was an ogre.
```

If you want to filter the log on certain keywords then you can use this crude and somewhat wrong MVP:

```
$ git log --grep='Keywords:.*ogrekin'
commit b307a1c02eec479888cba7676e00903071fb0878
Author: Victor Version Control <vvc@vcs.org>
Date:   Fri Sep 24 20:59:46 2021 +0200

    Start the story

    Keywords: intro, ogrekin
```